# Ho to emulate Grab/Move (G) with python script?

Tags: python, scripting

After a few hours of searching, I have not found documentation on how to emulate the pressure of the "G" key that allows you to move an object freely with the mouse. I have a modal function and I would like to insert this command to select an object and keep it on the mouse.

the command on blender suggests `bpy.ops.transform.translate()`
but I can not find options for this.

Comment: This question was asked previously and don't have an answer, may be there's no way to do that, but don't delete your question, may be now it would have a answer.

Comment: I think is possible. Addon "Snap utilities" have inside a function "Move" and that function similar to what I'm looking for  :)

Comment: If you have fixed that, post your answer so others can see it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this question searching solution for same one. I use this line : `bpy.ops.transform.translate('INVOKE_DEFAULT')`. It  emulates the "G" key for me.